# Restrict class to trait and structural subtype in Scala

Tags: scala, subtype

I need to restrict a Scala method parameter so that it implements both a trait and a structural subtype. How can I do this?

```
trait Foo
// ...
def someMethod[A <: Foo xxx { def close() }](resource: A)(block: A => Unit) {
  // ...
}
```

What do I put in place of `xxx`? I tried both `extends` and `with`, but got syntax errors.

Can it be done using a `type` definition for the structural subtype?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `type` for this:

```
type CanBeClosed = {def close()}

def someMethod[A <: Foo with CanBeClosed](resource: A)(block: A => Unit) {
  // ...
}
```

---

Recently I also wrote post about similar topic:

http://hacking-scala.posterous.com/composing-your-types-on-fly

Answer (score 7):

I'm actually not sure, if this is the same thing as what tenshi suggested, but it compiles, so try it out...

```
def someMethod[A <: Foo { def close() }](resource: A)(block: A => Unit) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm going with tenshi's solution because it allows more than one trait: `A <: Foo with Bar with CanBeClosed`, but thanks for the answer. I may use this syntax when I only have one trait.

Comment: `[A <: Foo with Bar { def close() }]` believe it or not, this works just fine ;)